# QXmlStreamReader.readNextStartElement() reads start elements twice

Tags: c++, xml, qt

I have a QXmlStreamReader variable and I want it to go over my xml file- QFile, and read all the start elements by the function readNextStartElement().
But it gives me every start tag **twice**.

Here is my code:

```
QXmlStreamReader* xmlReader = new QXmlStreamReader(orFile);
xmlReader->readNextStartElement();
std::string tagName = (orXmlReader->name()).toLocal8Bit().constData();
cout << tagName;
xmlReader->readNextStartElement();
tagName = (orXmlReader->name()).toLocal8Bit().constData();
cout << tagName;
```

Can someone help me find a solution? I there another function that can read normally the start elements?

Comment: Totally unrelated to the actual question: `cout << qPrintable(orXmlReader->name())` would save you some typing

Comment: This function reads **all** the elements and Returns true when a start element was reached. When the end element was reached, or when an error occurred, false is returned. 
That's why sometimes it looks like it reads twice an element - because it read the start element and than the end one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That API is confusing indeed and the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qxmlstreamreader.html#readNextStartElement) doesn’t help much for this particular case.

I think two things are worth mentioning:

1. The function is usually used in a context where you consume the content of the current element before calling readNextStartElement() again, e.g. readElementText() to get the content. If used like that, the problem doesn’t occur.
2. When calling the function while the position is already a start element (as it is after the tag was reported the first time), the function returns `false` without changing the position. Only the next call moves the position (and returns `true` in the good case).

So in our example, you can either actually read the content of the tag, or check the return value of readNextStartElement() and ignore it when it returns `false`. That might then ignore some valid error cases though.

Comment: Sometimes even if I call the function twice - I don't get the next start element.